# what do I tweak to manipulate the gaps between bullets/numbers and list items?

Tags: css

Simple question - what part of my CSS do I tweak to adjust the gap between a bullet/number and the first text character in an HTML list?

Bonus question - I've seen it mentioned here that controlling table spacing by adjust padding on `table tr td {}` is bad practice, but I haven't seen someone explain how you're really supposed to do it...?

Comment: Perhaps you're confused. The `td` attributes `cellspacing` and `cellpadding` are depreciated, and should be avoided. Using css to control `padding` of `td` elements is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

margin and padding should do it.

i see no reason why you can't have padding on a td.  i do it and it works well.  i think what people are moving towards now is a model of using divs and placing them like tables using css.

```
<html>

<style>
    ul {}
    li { padding:0 0 0 30px ;}
</style>

<body>
    <ul>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
    </ul>
</body>

</html>
```